# Define variable type Ruby in function declaration

Tags: ruby

How can i declare variable type in function definition?

In the next code:

```
def f(a, b)
#...
end
```

I can forget with what type it works with. How can i declare that it is a fixnum? Thanks

Comment: Ruby has weak typing. Variables indeed do have a class type when instanciated, but you can freely reassign them to another variable type. Only way to store this info is in the documentation of your function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points of confusion in your question:

1. Variables don't have types in Ruby. Only objects do.
2. `Fixnum` is not a type, it is a class. Classes aren't types. *Protocols* are types. *Any* object which speaks the correct protocol is of the same type. Some examples of well-known protocols in Ruby that do not have a corresponding class or mixin are what I will call the **Appendable** protocol (consisting of a method named `<<` that appends its argument to its receiver) or the **Iterable** protocol (consisting of a method named `each` which `yield`s each of its receiver's elements in turn). [Note: I made up those names. In reality, those Protocols are so deeply ingrained in Ruby culture that they don't even have names.]

In general, you will describe the protocol(s) your method expects from its arguments in the documentation of the method, but sometimes this description is left out if e.g. it is obvious from the name of the method or the name of the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

See comments and the other answers for a clarification about what is really a "type".

How you can test a "variable's type" (in Ruby every variable references an object and we don't talk about types but classes)

How you can test for a class :

```
variable = MyClass.new
variable.class # => "MyClass"
variable.is_a?(MyClass) # => true
```

But typically in Ruby we are more interested in what the object can do, what we can do with them :

```
if variable.respond_to?(increment)
  variable.increment
else
  raise "Error : must provide as 'variable' an object that can increment itself"
end
```

Now to answer your question, I would "declare" the behavior in the function definition / comments using rdoc syntax

```
# Description of f
# Params:
# +a+:: command line string to be executed by the system
# +b+:: +Proc+ object that ....
def f(a, b)
  # code
end
```

Comment: This will *not* tell you a "variable's type". It will you the *class* of the *object*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Then please tell me the difference between the class of the object and the "variable type".
In Ruby all variables we manipulate are actually "classes" so it doesn't make sense to talk about "type". That or I didn't understand the OP's question.

Comment: Classes aren't types. *Protocols* are types. *Any* object which speaks the correct protocol is of the same type. Some examples of well-known protocols in Ruby that do not have a corresponding class or mixin are what I will call the **Appendable** protocol (consisting of a method named `<<` that appends its argument to its receiver) or the **Iterable** protocol (consisting of a method named `each` which `yield`s each of its receiver's elements in turn). [Note: I made up those names. In reality, those Protocols are so deeply ingrained in Ruby culture that they don't even have names.]

Comment: Variables are *not* classes. They aren't even objects. Objects are instances of classes. Variables are not. Variables have neither classes nor types. The code you showed tests what the class of the object the variable *points to* is, which is *completely different* from the class of a variable (should such a thing exist, which it doesn't).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Consider two objects _object1_ and _object2_ which may or may not be of the same class. And if both respond to exactly the same methods, would it be correct to say that they are both of the same _type_?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: Yes, exactly. In OO, the type (or rather the types) of an object is (are) the protocol(s) it speaks. A good example in Ruby is the `StringIO` class from the `stringio` library. Instances of `StringIO` are supposed to be useable everywhere instances of `IO` are. (The purpose of `StringIO` is for "fake" IO objects that are backed by regular strings instead of files, network sockets, pipes, etc.) So, instances of `IO` and `StringIO` have the same *type*, but they don't share any common classes except `Object`.

Comment: Think about this: the Liskov Substitution Principle tells us when it is allowed for one type to be a subtype of another. `S <: T` iff and only iff an instance of `S` can be used whereever an instance of `T` is expected without changing the meaning of the program. But, you can also read this in reverse: if an instance of `S` can be used where an instance of `T` is expected, then `S <: T`. If instances of `S` and instances of `T` speak the same protocol, then any instance of `S` can be used in place of `T` and any instance of `T` can be used in place of `S`, which means `S` is both a subtype …

Comment: … and a supertype of `T`, which in turn means that `S` and `T` are the same type. This notion of "protocol" was first developed in Smalltalk. However, in Smalltalk (just like in Ruby), it is informal and exists only in documentation. (In Smalltalk, it is also built into the IDE, usually.) When Brad Cox and Tom Love designed Objective-C based on Smalltalk in 1982, they took this informal idea of protocol and made it a part of the language. When Patrick Naughton et al. designed Java based on Objective-C, they kept the idea of protocols but renamed them `interface`s.

Comment: In Java, `interface`s define object types, whereas `class`es define Abstract Data Types. So, if you use Java purely as an object-oriented language, then you shouldn't use classes as types, only interfaces. The Java notion of interface is equivalent to Ruby's notion of protocol.

Comment: There are only a very few places in Ruby, where Ruby actually *requires* a certain class. Usually, this is because in this particular case, Ruby breaks with object-oriented principles for performance reasons. But even in those very specific cases, Ruby provides an escape hatch: rather then requiring that an object be of a certain class, it only requires that it implements a certain conversion protocol for that class. For example, for passing a piece of code as if it was a block, Ruby requires a `Proc` object. But you don't *have* to pass a `Proc`, you can also pass something that *returns* …

Comment: … a `Proc` when you call `to_proc`, which is what enables the `Symbol#to_proc` and `Method#to_proc` hacks like `(1..42).map(&:to_i)` and `(1..42).each(&method(:puts))`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you so much. All very very interesting and given me some new concepts to research further.